# Swift -How to Paginate when Swiping Down

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, keyboard, scrollview

When loading posts, the most recent post is usually at the top of the screen and as the user **swipes up**, once the scrollView hits the bottom of the screen older posts shown are using this method

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    if maximumOffset - contentOffset <= 40 {

        handlePagination()
    }
}
```

But when loading messages it's the exact opposite. The most recent message is at the bottom of the screen and as the user **swipes down** once the scrollView hits the top of the screen older messages are shown.

There are 2 situations to take into account:

1- there is usually a textField or a textView with a sendButton at the bottom of the screen. If the user doesn't touch the textField/ or textView, they can just swipe down and once the scrollView hits the top of the screen `handlePagination()` will get called to show older messages

2- If the user touches the textView/Field, the keyboard is raised, even if they type some text into the textView/Field they can still swipe down to view older messages

The questions are

**1. How can I detect when the user scrolls down so I can call `handlePaginate()` when the scrollView hits the top of the screen**

and

**2. Do I need to take the keyboard's height into consideration when it is raised while doing that?**

I can use the keyboard notifications to detect when the keyboard is or isn't raised and simply toggle a property to the keyboard's height.

```
var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

    guard let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else { return }
    guard let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }

    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
}

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {

    keyboardHeight = 0.0
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I only had to check if the contentOffset was less then or equal to 50

```
if contentOffset <= -40 {
    handlePagination()
}
```

It worked when the keyboard was and wasn't raised.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if contentOffset <= -40 {
        handlePagination()
    }
}
```